# Tengo un problema a acceder desde la consola env\Scripts\activate

Tags: python-3.7

PS C:\Users\SQA\Desktop\Djangocrud\env\Scripts> activate
activate : El término 'activate' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.
Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

- activate
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: En Windows la forma de activar un entorno virtual es (situándonos en la raíz de nuestro proyecto) -> `nombre_entorno\Scripts\activate.bat`

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, pregunta al digitar el comando en la consola de visual studio code, como tu lo describes, no queda activado...

Comment: PS C:\Users\SQA\Desktop\Djangocrud> env\Scripts\activate.bat
PS C:\Users\SQA\Desktop\Djangocrud> env\Scripts\activate.bat
PS C:\Users\SQA\Desktop\Djangocrud>

Comment: Estas en un powershell, utiliza el CMD (command prompt)